# eclipse compiler compliance bug 1.6

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So The problem I'm encountering is that in the problems tab of eclipse it is telling me
"Syntax error, type annotations are available only when source level is at least 1.8"
But when I change the compiler compliance level to 1.8 I get the error 
"android compiler requires 5.0 or 6.0 to run change this in android-tools -> fix project properties" 
(roughly) This changes the compiler compliance level to 1.6...then I get the other error.

When I fix one the other comes up. Am I being crazy? Or am I going around in circles trying to fix this lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is not crazy, it is actually preventing you to write a code, which will not work on any android device. You are trying to use [Type annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html), which is Java 8 feature, in an android project, which is not possible. Android only supports Java version 6 or lower and hence the errors.